# Any ways build docs by sphinx with both python2.x and python3.x ecosystems?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have [a project](https://bitbucket.org/estin/pomp) that supports both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x using a single code base. In it, I used optional futures:

- Twisted (Python 2.x only)
- [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) (Python 3.2 only)

If application runs on Python 2.x then Twisted is available.

If application runs on Python 3.2+ then `concurent.futures` is available.

I want to build docs using Sphinx for the whole project, but how I can do that for both ecosystems?

Comment: If your document does not use use :autodoc: feature then there should be no problem. If it does use, you can create two main index.rst files, each lists document pages available in one codebase.

Comment: :autodoc: used in project. two index.rst its means two separate docs or two separate environment for sphinx.
For me ideal use case it smart :autodoc: with `mock` all imports

Comment: Also if the code is importable on both Python versions (which is should be... otherwise you cannot run it) autodoc should just work

Comment: You need to mock one of the packages. This should not be a problem if your appcode doesn't actually use the said packages at import time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem I release [mockautodoc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-mockautodoc) sphinx extension